# SweetAlert2 doesn't seem to work for me . What have i done wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, notifications, sweetalert2

[Here is the link to a simple source code example](https://github.com/solow-crypt/error/blob/main/modaltrial.html) . I don't know what have I done wrong , I seem to get a reply when i press the button and i can prove it because of notie code.

Here is a minimal reproducible code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/notie/dist/notie.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.16.6/sweetalert2.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div><input type="submit" id="swale" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Make Registration"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/notie"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>



    <script>
        document.getElementById("swale").addEventListener("click", function(){
            notify("This is a success message", "success")
            notifyModal()
        })

        function notify(msg,msgType){
            notie.alert({
            type: msgType,
            text: msg,
            })
        }

        function notifyModal(){
            swal.fire({
                title: "title",
                html: "<em> hello, world </em>",
                icon: "success",
                confirmButtonText: "wsd"
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] within the question itself.

Comment: @SuperStormer I have changed my question as you said.

Comment: Your code works fine. https://prnt.sc/138sa05

Comment: @Alaksander Jesus Gene for some reason , the code works on stackoverflow but doesnt work for me see @ https://prnt.sc/139qgzw. The console of the browser shows this error https://prnt.sc/139qlxq

Answer (score 0):

you have to call styles sweetalert2 in your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.16.6/sweetalert2.css">
```

Comment: I did try that but it still wouldnt work for some unknown reason .